# BASH - Escape three backslash

Tags: bash

I want to display three backslashes in bash. I tried the codes below:

```
myString='\\\hello world'
echo ${myString} # output is '\\hello world'
```

I'm planning to put all kinds of special characters in the string. My question is how to treat it like a string and not escape any characters. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code works in bash, but you're probably incorrectly running it with `sh`. In any case, use `printf` to avoid any unexpected expansions:

```
myString='\\\hello world'
printf '%s\n' "${myString}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
test="\\\\\\hello world"
echo $test
```

You need to mask each special char (backslash) with an backslash. You need 3 special chars, so you need 3 backslashs.

Comment: Can I do it without manipulating the string itself? I mean, what if the text is too long, I need to manually put another backslash in every backslash just to escape.

Comment: In this case, you need to use **printf**, like the answer from @that-other-guy